# Matplotlib: Channel Occupation Plot From Lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a channel occupation plot with Matplotlib. Let me explain what I'm trying to do.

Say, I have a communication channel (e.g. a telephone line) that is occupied by two different parties as defined by the following lists:

```
occupation_start_times = [[1,2,3],[1.5,2.5,3.5]]
occupation_durations = [[0.3,0.2,0.2],[0.4,0.2,0.1]]
```

So basically party 1 occupies the channel from 1 to 1.3, 2 to 2.2 and 3 to 3.2, and party 2 from 1.5 to 1.9 and so forth.

For each party I'd like to have a distinct horizontally aligned area where each period of channel occupation is represented by a bar (or rather a rectangular shape). I need such a distinct plot for each party, because multiple parties may seize the channel at the same time.

I already considered [this](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html), but the problem is that there's only one horizontal bar per party instead of multiple bars interrupted by times where the channel is not seized by that party.

Comment: I would guess that you are looking for some kind of Gantt-chart like [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html). If you have a problem of implementation, we need a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I was able to solve my problem based on the link of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest!

[image: Picture]

Part of myplot class... Just remove all `self`s and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and customize to your needs, voilà!

```
def broken_barh(self):
    plot_data = []
    for index,item in enumerate(self.data["occupation_starting"]):
        plot_data.append(list(zip(self.data["occupation_starting"][index], self.data["occupation_durations"][index])))

    print("plot_data:")
    #print(plot_data)
    data_len = len(plot_data)
    print(data_len)

    self.ax.set_ylim(5, 5*data_len+15)
    self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.timer*self.repetitions)
    self.ax.xaxis.grid(self.grid)
    self.ax.yaxis.grid(self.grid)

    # FIXME: Now ACKS are absolutely required, or data_len/2 doesn't make sense!
    self.ax.set_yticks([x*10+15 for x in range(int(data_len/2))])
    #self.ax.set_yticklabels(["measurement "+str(self.measurement[index]) for index in range(int(data_len/2))])

    self.setLabels(
        xlabel="time[s]",
        title=self.title
    )

    blue_patch  = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label="Data")
    red_patch   = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Acks')

    if self.legend_coordinates[2] != "best":
        self.ax.legend( handles=[red_patch, blue_patch],
                        fancybox=True,
                        loc=self.legend_coordinates[2],
                        bbox_to_anchor=(self.legend_coordinates[0],
                                        self.legend_coordinates[1]))
    else:
        self.ax.legend( handles=[red_patch, blue_patch],
                        fancybox=True,
                        loc="best")

    for index,item in enumerate(plot_data):
        print("Added index "+str(index)+" to plot.")
        if index % 2 == 0:
            self.ax.broken_barh(item,((index+1)*5+5, 9), facecolors='blue')
        elif (index-1) % 2 == 0:
            self.ax.broken_barh(item,(index*5+5,9), facecolors='red')
```